# A society has to elect a board of governors.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

A society has to elect a board of governors. Each member of the society has chosen $10$ candidates for the board, but he will be happy if at least one of them will be on the board. For each six members of the society there exists a board consisting of two persons making all of these six members happy. Prove that a board consisting of $10$ persons can be elected making every member of the society happy.

**Comment:** I could easily find a board of $20$ governors. Suppose that the claim does not hold. Take any set $ \mathcal{G} =\{G_1,G_2,...G_{10}\}$ which makes happy member $M_1$. Since the claim does not hold there must be a member $M_2$ who is unhappy with that board, but there is board $\mathcal{G'} =\{G'_1,G'_2,...G'_{10}\}$ which does makes him happy. It is not difficult to see, because of the second assumption, that the board $ \mathcal{G} \cup \mathcal{G'}$ makes the whole society happy.

That is it. I can't go any further.

Comment: No info on how many members there are?

Comment: I don't think your $20$ member board argument is valid.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: No, there is no information about this. Why not, if you take any member $M$ and add any three to $M_1$ and $M_2$ we have six members, so there must be a board of two governors which makes them all happy and so does arbitrary member $M$. But these two governors must come from $\mathcal{G}\cup \mathcal{G}'$

Comment: If someone is interested, we have to halve both boards $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{G}'$ in to $A_1$ , $A_2$ and $B_1$, $B_2$. Then some board $A_1\cup B_1$, $A_1\cup B_2$, $A_2\cup B_1$ or $A_2\cup B_2$ is good. Try it your self with a contradiction. This is a solution which I don't like since there is no methodology to tell us how to come with such idea.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = [a_1,a_2...a_{10}]$ be the set of people that make $P_A$ happy. Then assume there exists $P_B$ (with set $B = [b_1,b_2...b_{10}])$ who is not happy with $A$ as the board and then as you've shown $A\cup B$ makes everyone happy.

Then assume $A\cup B$ is the minimum sized board st everyone is happy. Therefore there exists $C$ st $C \cap (A\cup B) = a_1$ as otherwise $a_1$ could be removed and everyone would still be happy with the board. By similar logic there exists $D$ st $D \cap (A\cup B) = a_2$. However if we put $A,B,C$ and $D$ in a group of $6$ there isn't a board of $2$ that makes all of them happy. Therefore we can remove either $a_1$ or $a_2$ and everyone would still be happy. Say we have just removed $a_1$ then there exists $E$ st $E \cap (A\cup B) = a_3$ or $[a_1,a_3]$ and there exists $F$ st $F \cap (A\cup B) = a_4$ or $[a_1,a_4]$ so therefore we can either remove $a_3$ or $a_4$ (using the same argument as before) or remove $a_3$ and $a_4$ and put $a_1$ back in, reducing the size of the board whatever the case.

We can continue this process removing all but one of $[a_1,a_2...a_{10}]$ and all but one of $[b_1,b_2...b_{10}]$ leaving a board of $2$. (I think there are still some problems with this argument). Therefore if there are $2$ people whose choices don't have anyone in common a board of $2$ is enough to make everyone happy and if not then $[a_1,a_2...a_{10}]$ makes everyone happy so a board of $10$ people is enough whatever.

Comment: And what if $P_C$ is not happy with $A\cup B$?

Comment: @Ennar $P_C$ has to be happy with $A \cup B$ as otherwise you can put $A,B$ and $C$ in a group of 6 and there isn't a board of two that makes them all happy.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read properly that that board consists of two members.